# spring security password encryption

Tags: database, spring, security, password-encryption

I am using spring security for DB authentication. Currently I am adding the user manually in db with username and password.
I have added db related information in spring-database.xml which is as follows

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    </bean>

     <bean class="com.medfusion.encoder.HashCode"
                 init-method="secureDatabase" depends-on="dataSource">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Hashcode.java

```
package com.medfusion.encoder;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowCallbackHandler;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

public class HashCode extends JdbcDaoSupport {

    public void secureDatabase() {
    getJdbcTemplate().query("select username, password,enabled from users",
                             new RowCallbackHandler(){
      @Override
      public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        String username = rs.getString(1);
        String password = rs.getString(2);
        Integer isEncoded = rs.getInt(3);
        if (isEncoded != null){
            if (isEncoded < 1 ){
                //only encode if not encoded..we need not re-encode each time else passwords wont match
                BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
                String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
                getJdbcTemplate().update("update users set password = ? ,enabled = 1 where username = ?", hashedPassword,username);
                logger.debug("Updating password for username:"+username+" to: "+hashedPassword);
            }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is...when I add a new user, the password is encrypted only when the server is restarted. This is because I have used init-method in XML. I dont want server restart, would prefer this happens without restart.
Any help would be appretiated

Comment: Welcome from StackOverflow. Visit our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page.

Comment: you haven't describe the insert user part. you need to encrypt the password at create time. this code you've shared, shows that on the application startup, all the users will be checked and their password will be encrypted if it is necessary